# Не передается опциональный параметр

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Добавил вот такой роут

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "calculator",
pattern: "{controller=Calculator}/{action=Index}/{a?}/{b?}")
```

При переходе по адресу https://localhost:5001/calculator/index/aa ожидаю, что a=aa, b=null. Но у меня оба параметра null.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему так?

Comment: В шаблоне определены два сегмента: `/{a?}/{b?}`. В адресе указан один сегмент: `/aa`. Поэтому маршрут не совпадает.

Comment: Либо задавайте два маршрута для одного и двух параметров. Либо гуглите по термину "catch-all": `{*param}`